# How to indicate mlagents-learn which parameters to test

Tags: unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I am starting to discover ML-Agents in Unity, and have some working code with a cube moving in 2d. I have now implemented the detection of space key for the cube to jump. I would like to instruct mlagents-learn to test this space-key during simulation, or any other parameter. Where should this be done so that the ActionBuffers array gets properly filled?

Comment: thats the whole point of ML. You reward for correct behavior and punish bad. It then works out what works

Comment: exactly what @BugFinder already said: You don't! It will figure it out completely itself. It will start with completely random output until it starts to note that certain values resulted in better rewards while others resulted in worse or even punishment. Based on that it will then try to learn a reason (actual rather pattern) and just try more and more often to maximize its rewards => it learns bit by bit which are the best values to apply - it will not understand at all what those values actually mean! for the ML agent it just receives an array of values and creates a new array of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it. I need to use a discrete branch with size of 2 (for ones and zeros), then apply it as jump.